# Is 600 hours of teaching per year a lot in Germany? What does it look like?

Tags: teaching, professorship, university, germany

As a professor at a university of applied science in Germany, is 600 hours of teaching considered a lot? What does it look like? The job description says:

> Die Arbeitszeit beträgt grundsätzlich 40 Stunden pro Woche. Der Mitarbeiter hält in der Vorlesungszeit Lehrveranstaltungen im Umfang von bis zu 600 Lehrveranstaltungsstunden pro Jahr ab.
>
> Working hours are generally 40 hours per week. During the lecture period, the employee holds courses amounting to up to 600 hours per year.

Comment: There are roughly 2000 work hours in a year (40 hours/week, 52 weeks a year, decrease to account for holiday and vacation appropriate to your country). So, roughly 1/3 time directly spent on teaching. Is that lectures only, or lectures plus grading plus advising plus ???

Comment: @JonCuster (Lehrveranstaltungen: course hours) maybe lectures as it mentioned in the statement above.

Comment: Perhaps yes, perhaps no. Sometimes instructors are paid based on 'contact hours' which includes lectures, office hours, and grading time. One of our German contributors likely has a better idea on that than I do. Frankly, I'd have a really hard time talking for that many hours in a lecture per day.

Comment: How are you counting hours of teaching? There is more time required than that standing in front of a class. If you count only hours actually spent lecturing then it is a lot, otherwise not so much.

Comment: @Buffy I think that's OP's question: how do Germans/this particular job description in Germany count time teaching. As Jon points out, if it's according to percentage of a typical work week it's a lot different than if it's some measure of time spent doing a specific activity, like actually standing up and lecturing .

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that a professorship at a university of applied science is essentially a teaching job, typically with rather minimal expectations for research output? That's surely relevant context for this question.

Comment: 40 hours per week, and on top of that 600 hours per year in lectures or facetime. Otherwise over the 250(?) school days a year, that's 2.4 hours a day. So not much, if it's "teaching", as in standing in front of a class talking. 600 hours of *extra* bs per year? yeah, that's a lot. And that's why I charge by the hour. At least they're up front about it.

Comment: @Mazura: *40 hours per week, and on top of that 600 hours per year in lectures or facetime* – It’s included, not on top.

Comment: *Is 600 hours per year **of lectures** a lot?* - 600 hours of *teaching* per year isn't even part time.

Comment: N.B.: "bis zu" = "Up to" means "surely no more, but could be less". Maybe it's only an _upper_ limit (for legal reasons)?

Comment: Your question says “university of applied science”, your comment to an answer says “private university”. That’s a relevant difference.

Comment: @CarstenS its a private university for applied science.

Comment: This is not about being technically correct, it is about getting the most useful answers. Private universities are unusual in Germany, who knows what they do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Counting German teaching load – Semesterwochenstunden

The typical unit of teaching in Germany is SWS (Semesterwochenstunden – hours per week per semester). One SWS corresponds to 45 minutes (German teaching hour) of lectures or similar over 14 or 15 weeks. Other teaching duties such as supervising theses, excursions, practicals etc. have official conversion rates to SWS. Also, professors can partially reduce their teaching loads by taking on certain teaching-related administrative roles such as being on the examination committee or supervising others who teach. However, preparation times, exam correction, etc. do not count as extra SWS.

A professorship at a university of applied science (Fachhochschulprofessur) is considerably different from a professorship at a “normal” university on account of its teaching focus. **The typical teaching load of a professor at a university of applied science is 18 SWS, which corresponds to roughly 540 hours (of 45 minutes) face time per year.** Thus, 600 hours seems somewhat high, but not overly high. The only people with such teaching loads have a position called *Lehrkraft für besondere Aufgaben* (teacher for special tasks), which has a teaching load of up to 24 SWS at universities of applied sciences (depending on the state); these are not professorships.

If you are unsure what a given position entails, I recommend to ask/look for SWS as this is the standard unit. If nothing further is specified, look at the respective state’s laws regarding the specific position. These teaching loads are pretty standardised.

#### What is it like?

Professors at universities of applied science typically spend their first few years entirely on building up teaching, i.e., creating material, developing routine, etc. **This is generally considered a very taxing phase** and many work more than 40 hours per week to manage this, often considerably more. However, this depends a lot on the specific position, accommodation by the university, and what material you already have. For example, if you can primarily use existing teaching material and have some repetition in your teaching duties (e.g., doing the same course twice), this can considerably ease the situation. If you are considering taking such a position, I strongly recommend to inquire what kind of support, existing material, etc. you can build upon during the first years.

Once they have done every course once or twice, professors typically can allot some of their time to other projects such as research, industry collaborations, committee work etc. What exactly is possible here depends a lot on the position. Still, teaching remains a primary aspect of such a professorship.

*This second half of the answer stems from my own investigation in such positions including long conversations with people who have recently acquired such a position.*

Comment: Nowadays, research is gettign more and more relevant for fachhochschulen. Hence, they are trying to accomodate new professors with a lot of help (reduced teaching, providing teaching material etc.). This is to prevent them loosing their connection to companies and instead starting with research as soon as possible.

Comment: @wrzlprmft many thanks for your input. I will be finishing my Ph.D next month and I will join them directly after the defence. They accepted my application ( after 8 months of evaluation and invited lectures). The promise now (as mentioned in the contract) is to send my documents to the ministry to check if I can get the prof title (if not, i will be as dozent. with the same salary I think?).  The university is an IT private university and they want to establish a new program for bachelor and master in data science.

Comment: +1. Most German institutes of higher education work on a model of two semesters per year, but some differ (e.g., AFAIK the *Bundeswehr* universities run three semesters, and *Berufsakademien* have students alternate three months of lectures with three months of practical work). This may make *Lehrveranstaltungsstunden* more relevant than *SWS*. As always, it's good to understand the details, rather than expect 18 *SWS* and two semesters per year, only to find out that it's 18 *SWS* but *three* semesters.

Comment: @Krebto "private university"? Then take all answers here with a grain of salt, as private universities may do some things differently than standard Universitäten and Fachhochschulen. In the context of your question: Especially check whether they use semesters or trimesters and whether your position is "teaching only" or does include time for research. Then you may be able to determine the impact of the hours given in your question.

Comment: @Krebto: A thing you need to check (of they'll tell you, but it might be too late), if you are getting the title. This is governed by the local ("Bundesland") jurisdiction, there is a law on university teaching in each of them, with somewhat different, but similar details. One common requirement is *3 years of industry experience*, i.e. "outside" of the university. Also, the typical state UAS have 18 SWS workload, while you have more, as was already mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

[Here](https://glossar.hs-mittweida.de/Lehrveranstaltungsstunde) (in German), it says that 15 Lehrveranstaltungsstunden are roughly equivalent to 1 Semsterwochenstunde (SWS) (perhaps are more widely known term). Divide 600 by 15, that makes 40 SWS a year, or 20 per semester.

[This table](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehrdeputat) gives the normal amounts of SWS for professors in different federal states in Germany (both for university and university of applied sciences): 8-10 per semester for university professors and 16-18 for those at applied sciences.

So if those hours don't include preaparation (and according to the definition in source 1 they don't), the answer is: **Yes, that is a lot of hours.**

Comment: I agree with your answer but would like to add that 1 Lehrveranstaltungsstunde is usually 45 minutes, not 60 minutes.

Comment: This seems to count only the face-time with students in lecture. There is more to teaching than that.

Comment: @LuckyPal I know, it even says so in link 1. I don' t know where you think I spoke of 60 min, because I did not.

Comment: @Sursula-they- I did not intend to mean that you were speaking of 60 minutes. I just felt it was an important addition to your otherwise perfectly well formulated answer, as in this thread nobody has mentioned yet that a teaching hour in Germany is 45 minutes, which afaik is not a universal concept across the world and typically an hour will be understood as 60 minutes.

Comment: @Buffy Certainly correct. When counting teaching hours, preparation, grading, exam preparing, etc. is normally excluded in Germany. The usage of the term "Lehrveranstaltungsstunde" indicates that this is meant here as well, as this roughly translates to "teaching event hours" - the number of hours spent in events.

Comment: Also dont forget exam correction and tutorial submissions.